# Visualize gradle task dependencies

Tags: gradle

I'm looking for a tool that will graphically display the task dependency graph for a Gradle script, but could not find any.
Please mention tools that you worked with that can do it, or explain if this can't be done.
Thanks!

Comment: ? https://www.google.de/#q=gradle+script+visualizer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [gradle-task-tree](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) plugin can print an ascii tree to the console.

There's also the [gradle-visteg](https://github.com/mmalohlava/gradle-visteg) plugin which creates a [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) file

Comment: And, I might add, [gradle-taskinfo](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-taskinfo#gradle-taskinfo). 

Comment: what versions does it support? I can't get it to work.